# Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\begin' failed!

Tags: etoolbox

After updating my MiKTeX 2.9 package, `.tex` files which compiled perfectly with 0 error 0 warning now gives 0 error 1 warning:

```
Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\begin' failed!  (pdflatex)
(etoolbox)  'AtBeginenvironment' will not work
```

A minimum working example is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}
   MWE!
\end{document}
```

I don't really like to let unanswered warnings piling ups at the end of compilations, what, short of not using one of the two packages, can I do to suppress the warning?

Comment: Beware of using `html.sty`: it's a rather old and unmaintained package.

Answer (score 6):

Because the minimum working example is short enough, it is tempting to try to run the `datetime` package before the `html` one, it gives

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{html}
\begin{document}
  MWE!
\end{document}
```

Surprisingly, it works, there is no more warning!

Comment: Probably what happens here is that `datetime` loads `etoolbox` and patches successfully, while in the MWE in the question the `html` package probably alters `\document` in some very odd way. An alternative work around would therefore be to load `etoolbox` directly at some stage before loading `html`.

Comment: In a different document using `revtex4-1`, I resolved a similar warning by loading `etoolbox` immediately after declaring `\documentclass`.