# Request: LaTeX packages supported by knitr+RStudio

Tags: knitr, big-list, rstudio

**Question:** Is there a list anywhere of R packages which work with knitr+RStudio?

(Note: I already changed RStudio's defaults to use xeLaTeX and knitr instead of PDFLaTeX and Sweave, since my default TeX compiler in TeXStuido is xeLaTeX.)

**Background:** For example, this person had a problem [because of the LaTeX package `framed.sty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234559/knitr-in-rstudio-produces-undefined-control-sequence-alongside-other-issues), this person had a problem [because of the LaTeX packages `html.sty` and `etoolbox.sty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128938/package-etoolbox-warning-patching-begin-failed) (I have also had problems with `etoolbox` I think).

But even more glaringly, [in this MWE from Yihui Xue's website](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw), if one includes the `\usepackage{breakurl}` line when trying to compile in RStudio, the process breaks down, but if one removes that line, then suddenly everything works without a problem.

I imagine it works fine from the command line, but I don't even know how to use LaTeX, xeLaTeX, or R from the command line, much less all three at the same time.

Such a list would be useful for complete novices like me who are barely getting used to how the workflow works, and are not good at diagnosing problems based on error messages thrown by RStudio's calls to LaTeX.